# invalid host header mysql react heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I am trying to deploy a mysql express react app to heroku but I am getting a message on the deployed project invalid host header I am using a proxy in my client side package json:

```
{
"name": "crud",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",
"dependencies": {
"axios": "^0.18.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.1",
"morgan": "^1.9.1",
"react": "^16.8.4",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"react-bootstrap-modal": "^4.2.0",
"react-confirm-alert": "^2.3.0",
"react-dom": "^16.8.4",
"react-router-dom": "^4.4.0",
"react-scripts": "2.1.8"
},
```

my server.js file looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const logger = require("morgan")
// Initialize Express
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const db = require("./models");
//Middleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
// Routes
const apiRoutes = require("./routes/API");
app.use("/api", apiRoutes);
// API
// app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
// app.use("/auth", authRoutes);
// app.use("/authorize", dashRoutes)

// Configure middleware
// Use morgan
app.use(logger("dev"));
// Use body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// Use cors
app.use(cors());

// Connecting to DB

// Serve up static assets (usually on heroku)
// 


db.sequelize.sync({})

app.get("*", function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
});

app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log(`APP listening on PORT ${PORT}`)
});
```

I have tried using a .env.production file but that doesn't seem to work either, 
any ideas?

Comment: What's the proxy for? Generally speaking, you *must* use the port that Heroku provides via the `PORT` environment variable and you *cannot* use any other ports, e.g. `localhost:5000`.

Comment: The proxy Is there so it can api call the back end

Comment: What's the difference between the api and the back end? Do you mean so the _client_ can call the back-end? In any case, you won't be able to run that proxy on Heroku. Bind directly to the `PORT` it gives you and use that.

Comment: So I guess what would I do to bind to the port? Because when I removed the proxy the front end worked but the back end calls returned a 404

Comment: It looks like you're already doing it. You get it via `process.env.PORT`. But your React code needs to know where to talk to and you haven't shown that to us so I can't comment on it. It would be very common to have a variable for the "base URL" and set that at build time, e.g. via an environment variable on Heroku. (In other words, try hitting your Heroku site on port 80 and see if your API is responding. It probably is. Your new problem is on the front-end.)